# How to melt by all combination pairs of a column?

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dplyr

I have the following table, and I want to sum up the number of visits per path for each pair of channels, that is - the sum of the visits for the paths in which the pair of channels appear together.

Input:

```
   Channel PathNum visits
1       C1       1      5
2       C2       1      5
3       C3       1      5
4       C1       2      3
5       C2       2      3
6       C1       3      1
7       C4       4      4
8       C5       5     13
9       C6       5     13
10      C6       6      7
11      C6       6      7
```

Output:

```
   Channel1 Channel2 visits
1        C1       C1      9
2        C1       C2      8
3        C1       C3      5
4        C1       C4      0
5        C1       C5      0
6        C1       C6      0
7        C2       C2      8
8        C2       C3      5
9        C2       C4      0
10       C2       C5      0
11       C2       C6      0
12       C3       C3      5
13       C3       C4      0
14       C3       C5      0
15       C3       C6      0
16       C4       C4      4
17       C4       C5      0
18       C4       C6      0
19       C5       C5     13
20       C5       C6     13
21       C6       C6     20
```

Here is some R code using a for loop to do it for the above example:

```
df1 = data.frame(Channel=c("C1","C2","C3","C1","C2","C1","C4","C5","C6","C6","C6"), PathNum = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,6), visits=c(5,5,5,3,3,1,4,13,13,7,7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 =dcast(data = df1, PathNum ~ Channel, fun.aggregate=function(x){sum(x)/length(x)})
Channel1=NULL
Channel2=NULL
vis=NULL
for (i in 1:length(unique(df1$Channel))){
  for (j in i:length(unique(df1$Channel))){
    Channel1=c(Channel1, unique(df1$Channel)[i])
    Channel2=c(Channel2, unique(df1$Channel)[j])
    vis=c(vis,sum(df2[!is.na(df2[,unique(df1$Channel)[i]]) & !is.na(df2[,unique(df1$Channel)[j]]) & df2[,unique(df1$Channel)[j]]>0  , unique(df1$Channel)[i]]))
  } 
}

outframe = data.frame(Channel1=Channel1, Channel2=Channel2, visits=vis)
```

This works for this small example, but I was wondering if there is a good way of doing this with dplyr or SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
require(data.table)
require(gtools)
DT <- data.table(df1)

# get combos
uC   <- unique(DT$Channel)
cn   <- combinations(length(uC),2,repeats.allowed=TRUE)
cn[] <- uC[cn]

# get combos conditional on path
sharedPaths <- unique(DT)[,{
  cn <- combinations(.N,2,repeats.allowed=TRUE)
  list(v=visits[1],c1=Channel[cn[,1]],c2=Channel[cn[,2]])
},by=PathNum]   

# merge and sum
setkey(sharedPaths,c1,c2)
sharedPaths[J(as.data.table(cn)),sum(v,na.rm=TRUE),by=.EACHI]
```

Comment: Thanks, but for the updated example this fails though, first of all it doesn't include the zero value rows, but more importantly it miscounts if there are two of the same Channel in the same path (the path should only be counted once).

I get "C6 C6" to be 34, with this code, where it should be 20.