# Expand data frame into combinations of row pairs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that contains an identifier / key column followed by several rows of value columns.
I want to expand the data column by taking unique pairs of entries in the key column as the new rows and transform the value columns using binary operations on the entries from the corresponding rows.

E.g.

```
> Test_data
         SYS dE_water_free dE_water_periodic dE_membrane_periodic    RTlogKi
1 4NTJ_D294N       -56.542           -56.642                   NA -0.9629731
2  4NTJ_wild      -171.031          -162.030                   NA -0.8877264
3 4PXZ_D294N       -53.430           -50.810                   NA -1.1301124
4  4PXZ_wild       -59.990           -57.320                   NA -1.2318835
5 4PY0_D294N       -77.040           -72.880                   NA -1.1351579
6  4PY0_wild       -79.080           -74.950                   NA -1.2297302
```

Some of the columns may or may not contain missing value(s).

what I would like would be to take each pair of SYS entries, e.g. SYS1 SYS2 and compute a binary operation on the corresponding value rows
E.g. SYS1 SYS2 dE_water_free(SYS==SYS1)-dE_water_free(SYS==SYS2) ... etc

```
        SYS1       SYS2   dE_water_free   dE_water_periodic   ...etc.
1 4NTJ_D294N  4NTJ_wild         114.489             105.610
2 4NTJ_D294N 4PXZ_D294N          -3.112               5.832
... etc.
```

I can use the function `combn()` to get an array of pairs from the SYSTEM column to form the entries in SYS1 and SYS2, but I'm not sure how to use it to build the new data frame...

I know one option would be to use something like mapply and build each column individually by hand, then paste them all into a new data frame, but that seems like it will be klunky and slow and there should be a more automatic function to do this, like reshape, merge, or recast... but I can't seem to figure out how make that work.

Comment: Loosely related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30237924/1191259

Comment: By the way, if you want *all* pairs, like `A,B` and `B,A`, you'll want `expand.grid` (or `CJ` in the `data.table` package) rather than `combn`, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `combn` was a good way to go. Try this:

```
 combos<-combn(Test_data$SYS,2)
 water<-combn(Test_data$dE_water_free,2,FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2])
 data.frame(SYS1=combos[1,],SYS2=combos[2,],water,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 #         SYS1       SYS2    water
 #1  4NTJ_D294N  4NTJ_wild  114.489
 #2  4NTJ_D294N 4PXZ_D294N   -3.112
 #3  4NTJ_D294N  4PXZ_wild    3.448
 #4  4NTJ_D294N 4PY0_D294N   20.498
 #5  4NTJ_D294N  4PY0_wild   22.538
 ........
```

Comment: perfect that seems to be pretty much what i'm after. Is it possible to automatcially apply this to each of the value columns from the original data frame, or would I have to repeat for each column?

Comment: This does indeed work when wrapped in mapply: >mapply(function(y) combn(Test_data[,y],2,FUN=function(x) x[1]-x[2]),c("dE_water_free","dE_water_periodic"))

Answer (score 11):

`outer` is well suited for this type of problem:

```
de_wf <- with(Test_data, setNames(dE_water_free, SYS))
outer(de_wf, de_wf, `-`)
```

produces:

```
           4NTJ_D294N 4NTJ_wild 4PXZ_D294N 4PXZ_wild 4PY0_D294N 4PY0_wild
4NTJ_D294N      0.000   114.489     -3.112     3.448     20.498    22.538
4NTJ_wild    -114.489     0.000   -117.601  -111.041    -93.991   -91.951
4PXZ_D294N      3.112   117.601      0.000     6.560     23.610    25.650
4PXZ_wild      -3.448   111.041     -6.560     0.000     17.050    19.090
4PY0_D294N    -20.498    93.991    -23.610   -17.050      0.000     2.040
4PY0_wild     -22.538    91.951    -25.650   -19.090     -2.040     0.000
```

Comment: interesting, I may have to remember that command when I go to make correlation matrices. Unfortunately, I need to do this for several value columns so that I can make plots so the matrix / grid approach probably won't work out for me.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two solutions that take the Cartesian product/join of the data with itself.

**In base R**, I'd consider `outer`:

```
diffmat           <- with(Test_data,outer(dE_water_free,dE_water_free,`-`))
dimnames(diffmat) <- with(Test_data,list(SYS,SYS))
```

If you don't want the result in a matrix, there's

```
diffdf <- with(Test_data,data.frame(
  SYS1=SYS,
  SYS2=rep(SYS,each=length(SYS)),
  diff=c(diffmat)
))
```

**With `data.table`,** I'd use [@JanGorecki's `CJ.dt` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27347397/1191259)

```
require(data.table)
setDT(Test_data)

res <- CJ.dt(Test_data,Test_data)[,`:=`(
  freediff = dE_water_free-i.dE_water_free,
  perdiff  = dE_water_periodic-i.dE_water_periodic
)]
```

Comment: @BrodieG Yup. Your `setNames` beforehand is a nice shortcut :)

Comment: Hmm... I downloaded the optiRum package from CRAN and tried running: res <- CJ.dt(Test_data,Test_data)[,`:=`(freewdiff = dE_water_free - i.dE_water_free, perwdiff = dE_water_periodic - i.dE_water_periodic, permdiff = dE_membrane_periodic - i.dE_membrane_periodic)] ... but it gave me the error: "i.dE_water_free" not found.

Comment: @wmsmith I just copy-pasted the function from the answer I linked to and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Frank's solution looks a lot simpler and easier. But here's another approach with merges.

```
# Set Up
Test.data <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
  SYS = c("4NTJ_D294N",'4NTJ_wild',"4PXZ_D294N","4PXZ_wild","4PY0_D294N","4PY0_wild"),
  dE_water_free = c(-56.542,-171.031,-53.43,-59.99,-77.04,-79.08)
  )
```

New idea relying on dplyr

```
library("dplyr")
nuDat <- dplyr::left_join(
  dplyr::select(Test.data, Col1, SYS1 = SYS, dE_water_free1 = dE_water_free),
  dplyr::select(Test.data, Col1, SYS2 = SYS, dE_water_free2 = dE_water_free),
  by = "Col1"
  ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    dE_water_free = dE_water_free1 - dE_water_free2
    ) %>%
  dplyr::filter(SYS1 != SYS2) %>%
  dplyr::select(
    SYS1, SYS2, dE_water_free
    )
```