# (R programming) Create pairs of data in column Y based on duplicate values in column X

Tags: r, function, for-loop, duplicates

I am working on R
Assume all data are string
Also consider that  my actual dataset is ginormous

Column X has duplicates
When datum in X appears more than once, create all possible different pairs of Y (while x is constant) while also conserving column Z.

```
 X  Y    Z  
 1  a    RED   
 1  b    BLUE  
 1  c    PINK   
 1  d    YELLOW  
 2  a    PURPLE   
 3  a    ORANGE   
 3  b    GREEN  
 4  a    BLACK  
 4  b    WHITE   
 4  c    BROWN
```

So what I am trying to achieve as a result is

```
 X   Y1  Y2  Z1      Z2  
 1   a   b   RED     BLUE  
 1   a   c   RED     PINK  
 1   a   d   RED     YELLOW  
 1   b   c   BLUE    PINK  
 1   b   d   BLUE    YELLOW  
 1   c   d   PINK    YELLOW  
 2   a   NA  PURPLE  NA  
 3   a   b   ORANGE  GREEN  
 4   a   b   BLACK   WHITE  
 4   a   c   BLACK   BROWN  
 4   b   c   WHITE   BROWN
```

I think that the problem as to how to code "find and create all the different pairs of column" in R is solved by <[Expand data frame into combinations of row pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311908/expand-data-frame-into-combinations-of-row-pairs)>.
So my problem is how to code in R 
"**For every X, each time there are duplicates, group them together** to find and create all the possible pairs of Y and Z (for each specific X)"

I hope I made my problem clear!

Please help! :)

A tiny piece of my actual dataset (will have more columns) (X = parspecies; Y = hostspecies; Z = everything else) :

```
parspecies          |pargenus      |hostspecies               |hostgenus
----------------------------------------------------------------------   
Blattophagus beci   |Blatophagus     |Platyzostreia castanea        |Platyzostreia

Blissoxenos esakii  |Blissoxenos     |Dimorphopterus japonicus   |Dimorphopterus

Blissoxenos esakii  |Blissoxenos     |Iphicrates spinicaput         |Iphicrates

Blissoxenos esakii  |Blissoxenos     |Macropes obnubilus            Macropes

Caenocholax fenesi  |Caenocholax     |Camponotus atriaps        |Camponotus

Caenocholax fenesi  |Caenocholax     |Camponotus planatus       |Camponotus
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it in base R

```
#set up a list of matrices with the df$Y pairs (include NAs up to length 2)
combs <- tapply(df$Y,df$X,function(x) {length(x) <- max(2,length(x));return(t(combn(x,2)))})
#convert to a data.frame
df2 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,combs),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df2) <- c("Y1","Y2")
#recreate values of df$X that are lost by previous steps
df2$X <- rep(as.numeric(names(combs)),times=sapply(combs,nrow))
#merge in the colours in df$Z
df2 <- merge(df2,df,by.x=c("X","Y2"),by.y=c("X","Y"),all.x=TRUE)
df2 <- merge(df2,df,by.x=c("X","Y1"),by.y=c("X","Y"),all.x=TRUE,suffixes=c("1","2"))
#get correct column order after merge
df2[,4:5] <- df2[,5:4]

df2
   X Y1   Y2     Z1     Z2
1  1  a    b    RED   BLUE
2  1  a    c    RED   PINK
3  1  a    d    RED YELLOW
4  1  b    c   BLUE   PINK
5  1  b    d   BLUE YELLOW
6  1  c    d   PINK YELLOW
7  2  a <NA> PURPLE   <NA>
8  3  a    b ORANGE  GREEN
9  4  a    b  BLACK  WHITE
10 4  a    c  BLACK  BROWN
11 4  b    c  WHITE  BROWN
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                 Y = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c"), 
                 Z = c("RED", "BLUE", "PINK", "YELLOW", "PURPLE", "ORANGE", "GREEN", "BLACK", "WHITE", "BROWN"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think I understand how this should work, yet when i run it it gives me many many errors. I am sorry if I do something silly here but I am an absolute newbie... The errors are :
 > combs <- tapply(df$Y,df$X,function(x) {length(x) < max(2,length(x));return(t(combn(x,2)))})
Error in df$X : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of the errors?  It works on the example in your question, so there is obviously something different with your actual data.

Comment: I think I understand how this should work, yet when i run it it gives me many many errors. I am sorry if I do something silly here but I am an absolute newbie... The errors are :
 > combs <- tapply(df$Y,df$X,function(x) {length(x) < max(2,length(x));return(t(combn(x,2)))})
**Error in df$X : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable**
and because it gets this error then i get errors for **combs** and **df2** not found in the rest of the code

Comment: i use these test data and cannot get the proper results :/ i think because of this Error in df$X : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable error..

Comment: What do you get if you type `str(df$X)`?

Comment: the same error 
Error in df$X : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: I have added code for the df at the end of the answer - try using that - it works for me.

Comment: Yes it works. So it is a mistake by me as to how i entered my data. So all i did to enter the data was: df <- read.csv(file.choose()) and chose a CSV - UTF 8 (comma delimited) file from my desktop. What did i do wrong? I have got a file of some 100000s rows and 8-10 columns, and manually inserting the data does not help.. Should I add a bit of my actual dataset??  Thanks a lot for your help by the way!! I cannot believe how healthy this community is!!

Comment: That should work OK, but just have a look at your data after you have read it in to make sure it looks as you expect.  You might want to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your `read.csv` call.  If the CSV has come from Excel, check for odd characters in the first column name, and change the name if necessary (excel might add a mark to indicate UTF-8, which sometimes causes problems).

Comment: The data look nice without any weird characters.. yet i get the same error again. I will try stringsAsFactors=FALSE . Do you think that the code you gave me should work with data like the table i just added in my question right? It should be just false data entry in R by my part right? God it is so annoying being so ignorant in coding...

Comment: Read in the data to `df` and type `str(df)` - this will give you a summary of the structure of the data frame.  Check that the variable names are the same as the X, Y, Z, etc in the code, and that none of the variables are of an odd type such as `list`.

Comment: That's good!  Just a thought - if you have more than one 'Z' columns, the code will still work, but you might find it easier to delete the last line, and, in the line before, change the last item to `suffixes=c("2","1")`.

Comment: Hello Andrew
I am getting this error in this line of code (which i think happens because my actual data X column is string (names)):
**df2$X <- rep(as.numeric(names(combs)),times=sapply(combs,nrow))**
Warning message:
**NAs introduced by coercion**
So in result although it creates all the columns it should, I get <NA> in every value in the df2 :/
How do i tackle that?
Thanks a lot and I am really sorry for taking so much of your time!

Comment: Woooohooo I fixed it !! I figured it out!! Thanks a lot Andrew for all the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `by` with `merge` on itself for each X group.

```
dfList = by(df, df$X, function(i){
  tmp <- merge(i, i, by="X", suffix=c("1", "2"))

  if (nrow(tmp) > 1) {
    tmp <- subset(tmp, Y1 < Y2)[c("X","Y1","Y2","Z1","Z2")]
  } else {
    tmp[c("Y2","Z2")] <- NA
  }
  return(tmp)
})

newdf <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
rownames(newdf) <- NULL
newdf
#    X Y1   Y2     Z1     Z2
# 1  1  a    b    RED   BLUE
# 2  1  a    c    RED   PINK
# 3  1  a    d    RED YELLOW
# 4  1  b    c   BLUE   PINK
# 5  1  b    d   BLUE YELLOW
# 6  1  c    d   PINK YELLOW
# 7  2  a <NA> PURPLE   <NA>
# 8  3  a    b ORANGE  GREEN
# 9  4  a    b  BLACK  WHITE
# 10 4  a    c  BLACK  BROWN
# 11 4  b    c  WHITE  BROWN
```

Had it not been for the the special *PURPLE* (1-row group df), a one-liner would do:

```
dfList = by(df, df$X, function(i){
  subset(merge(i, i, by="X", suffix=c("1", "2")), Y1 < Y2)[c("X","Y1","Y2","Z1","Z2")]
})
```